# MySQL relations and query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `restaurants` and `meals`. Restaurants has

```
`id`
`name`
`menu`
`image`
`text`
`address`
```

Meals has

```
`meal_id`
`meal_name`
`meal_image`
`meal_weight`
`meal_price`
`meal_menu`
```

What I think to connect them `meal.restaurant.id`. Is this good approach or is better to make another (third) table and connect them there.

Can you provide me with a query how when restaurant with ID=1 is selected to show meals for this restaurant only. For now I think to hold restaurant id in `meal_menu` row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a pivot table e.g.

```sql
CREATE TABLE meal_restaurant
(
  meal_id int not null,
  restaurant_id int not null,
  primary key (meal_id, restaurant_id),
  foreign key (meal_id) references meals (meal_id),
  foreign key (restaurant_id) references restaurants (id) 
);
```

Now to select all meals for a specific restaurant you do

```sql
SELECT m.meal_id, meal_name, meal_image, meal_weight, meal_price
  FROM meals m JOIN meal_restaurant mr
    ON m.meal_id = mr.meal_id
 WHERE restaurant_id = 1
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0ebd5/2)** demo

Comment: So one more table wich hold meal_id and restaurant_id

Comment: In any case if I use one more table I don't need `meal.menu` row then. My idea for this field was to connect it with restaurant id. I don't use any data from there.

Comment: @JordanVit OK. Then get rid of this `menu` column and you're good. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

**if you think one restaurant has a many meal  and one meal has only one restaurant**

then you should try   restaurants  table

```
 `id`
 `name`
 `menu`
 `image`
 `text`
 `address`
```

Meals table

```
  `meal_id`
  `meal_name`
  `meal_image`
  `meal_weight`
  `meal_price`
  `meal_menu
  `restaurant_id`
```

**Or If you think one restaurant has a many meal  and one meal has many restaurant**

then you should try restaurants  table

```
 `id`
 `name`
 `menu`
 `image`
 `text`
 `address`
```

Meals table

```
  `meal_id`
  `meal_name`
  `meal_image`
  `meal_weight`
  `meal_price`
  `meal_menu
```

and restaurant_meal

```
  `restaurant_id`
  `meal_id`
```

restaurant_meal table only contain foreign key references restaurants table and meals table

it up  to  you which one you use ...you can use any  one.it just depend on requirement

Comment: This going to be `one restaurant has a many meal and one meal has only one restaurant `

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of your problem, you should make the `id` field of `restaurants` a primary key and the `meal_id` field of `meal` a foreign key that references the `id` field.

Comment: No, because I will hold all meals for 2 restaurants in `meal` table. That's why I can't select them via ID. I've made `restaurant` `id` primary and `meal_menu` foreign key for `restaurant.id`

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand then. You say you want to connect meals to a given restaurant but cannot select meals by ID?

Comment: Table `meals` will hold all meals. Row `meals_menu` will hold `1` or `2` where 1 and 2 are restaurants. So I need some query which when I choose restaurant 1 (id=1) to show me all the meals which has `meal.menu=1`. I hope is a bit clear now or I'm wrong in all conception?

Comment: `meal.menu` means you have a field in your `meal` table called `menu` but this is not the case according to your question. Can you clarify exactly which field you mean here?